# Can PHP be used to make desktop application or only make web-based application?

Tags: php

Can anybody tell me is a PHP desktop application possible? Like software we install on our computer system?

Comment: @shalu haan possible hain

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely possible to make desktop applications in PHP.

If you're looking for a starting place, I would check out (to cover the very basics):

[Building Desktop Applications with PHP](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/building-desktop-applications-in-php-8-02-01-934/)

Comment: ok thanks for reply.ya i m looking for starting place.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

- [php-gtk](http://gtk.php.net/)
- [winbinder](http://winbinder.org/)

PHP also comes with ncurses support if you are happy to deal with a character based front end.

However for standalone apps, you could do a lot worse that looking at HTML5's offline capability.

Answer (score 0):

its possible to make desktop applications using php. You can run your php independent of you apache server.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir How its possible any reference?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [bcompiler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.bcompiler.php) to enable the production of [php-gtk applications](http://gtk.php.net/) that could be used on client desktops, without the need for a php.exe. However, just because it is possible, does not mean it is practical. There is better platforms for developing desktop applications available.

Answer (score 0):

Is worth noting you can also use Phalanger (PHP in .net) and the .Net framework to do some of the same stuff. Interesting, but useless, really.

Answer (score 0):

PHP-GTK, WinBinder, etc... are very outdated and may not work in all three platforms. But the new opensource alternative is PHP Nightrain and it works great in all three platforms. Since the source is available you can always compile to any architecture you may need.

Here are some resources to help you develop cross platform GUI applications with PHP Nightrain:

http://www.naetech.com/php-nightrain

http://www.naetech.com/developing-ribbon-desktop-application-php.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXt8erPLf4o

Hope it helps!